# MySQL: programatically get list of binlog files

Tags: mysql, binlog

How can I programatically get a list of a particular mysql instance's binlogs?  ie. the same information provided by

```
mysql> show binary logs;
```

update: version 5.6 / AWS Aurora preferred.

Comment: What language in? What about `mysql -u... -p... -h... -e 'show binary logs'`?

Comment: This will be good as a backup, I'm hoping for some kind of query I can make over a mysql connection.

Comment: What mysql version do you use? 5.7 has an option to actually [fetch the binlogs in their binary form](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlbinlog-backup.html) from a [remote] server to a local filesystem.

Comment: For `show binary logs` I would _try_ the same mechanism as with regular SELECTs in whatever language you use. It returns some kind of _table_ after all and perhaps you're lucky.